# Show that if $S$ is a local ring, so is $R$ given that $R \subset S$ is an integral ring extension,

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $R \subset S$ be an integral ring extension. Prove that if $S$ is a local ring, so is $R$.

I do not see how I should do this. I know the definitions of local rings and integral extension, but I do not see how these two definitions are related. Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A standard result about integral ring extensions is that if $\mathfrak{p}$
is a prime ideal of $R$ then $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{P}\cap R$ for some
prime ideal $\mathfrak P$ of $S$.

If $R$ isn't local, it has at least two maximal ideals $\mathfrak m_i$
($i\in\{1,2\}$), and so $S$ has two prime ideals $\mathfrak P_i$
with $\mathfrak P_i\cap R=\mathfrak m_i$. Each $\mathfrak P_i$
is contained in the maximal ideal $\mathfrak M$ of $S$. This implies that
$\mathfrak M\cap R=\mathfrak m_1$ and $\mathfrak M\cap R=\mathfrak m_2$ which is
impossible.